# Only render a react component when I on submit from a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around only rendering a component after form data is submitted.

So I have an app that has the basic render:

```
(<div>
  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
  </form>
  <Results/>
</div>);
```

The idea is that onSubmit would dump some data into the `Results` component only at the time of submission.

Now I'll be honest the app would have values already within its state:

```
this.state = {
  length : 0,
  timeInSeconds: 0
}
```

So, I'd only want it to render or re-render this object when a user clicks the submit button and the onSubmit method executes.

I'm sorry this isn't clicking for me, but any advice or direction would be awesome!

Thanks,
Kelly

Comment: React component re-renders when new props are supplied or the component state changes. So, triggering a `setState` or changing the store value should re-render this component. Can you give us more data like how your component state looks like and how are you passing data to `Results` component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you flag a completion status at the end of our onSubmit and render the results conditionally? Something like:

```
this.state = {
  length : 0,
  timeInSeconds: 0,
  isSubmitted: false
}

onSubmit(e) {
    // Do something
    this.setState({isSubmitted: true})
}
```

Then place a condition to render the results.

```
(<div>
  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
  </form>
  {this.state.isSubmitted && <Results/>}
</div>);
```

Comment: Right, I just copied his render code. I edited onSubmit since I'm not sure he's really using an arrow function. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Felipe! Your `{this.state.isSubmitted && <Results/>}` was perfect! I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. I would do these kind of things when dealing with arrays of components. Again thank you! (sorry for the delay too, I had way too much going on)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. have a boolean in your component's state to indicate if form is
   being submitted or not. By default, it should be set to false. When the user clicks on submit, it should be updated to true.
2. pass this boolean's value to the Result component in props.
3. in Result component check the value of this prop value in render 
   method, and return the appropriate JSX (div with nested child or
   empty div).
4. set the boolean back to false when submit is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it. I did on the fly, but I'm pretty sure this is what you need. I hope am right :) Let me know if it was helpful

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react';
       import Results from './results';

       class FormData extends component {
             constructor(props) {
             super(props);
                  this.state = {
                  name: '',
                  age: null,
                  submitted: false
                  };
                    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
                    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
                  }
                    // Let's 1st make a onChane function and get the form data 
                   onChange(e) {
                     this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });  // Getting access to entered values
                  }

                // Let's make an onSubmit function
                  onSubmit(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();  // Here we prevent the default browser behavior
                    this.setState({isSubmitted: true}); // Let's set the new 'submitted state to TRUE

               // Gathering data in order to pass it to the <Results /> component

                    const formData = {
                      name: this.state.name,
                      age: this.state.age
                    };

                    this.props.makeResultsData(formData);  // Passing the data down as props
                  }

              // Let's render the necessary data including the results component 

           render() {
              return (

          // Little bit of destructuring
         // This is equal to const submitted = this.state.submitted
          { submitted } = this.state;  


        <div className="container">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <label>
                      Name:
                      placeholder="Enter your name"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                </label>
                <label>
                      Age:
                      placeholder="Enter your age"
                      name="age"
                      value={this.state.age}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
               </label>

        // Let's finally SUBMIT our form and change the states 'submitted' value to TRUE

               <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

         </form>

// With conditional rendering ,we can now display our <Results /> component, like this

  {this.state.isSubmitted && <Results/>}  // So, if submitted = true, render the Results component

        </div>
            );
          }
        }
```